# When editing order, uitabbaritem icons do not appear on edit view

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

In iOS 7, Apple has changed the background of the `tabBar`, edit screen (Where it says "Drag the icons to organize tabs.") to white.

**Problem:**
This causes a problem for me, in that my selected `tabbaritem` images are white, therefore you cannot see them on the edit view. It appears as if only the tabbaritems that are currently present (meaning, present in the tabbar) are editable (those icons do show up because they're red in their unselected state).

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to change the background color of the edit view?
2. Is there a way to change the icon colors only in the edit view?

Comment: I've tried to change the item image tint color on tabBar:willBeginCustomizingItems: but it seems that all the items that are located in the more tab are removed from the tabBar.items array at the time this is called, so I cannot change their color. This is such a silly issue! Is Apple trying to prevent the use of white icons in the tabBar?

Answer (score 0):

func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        willBeginCustomizingViewControllers viewControllers: [AnyObject]) {

```
        var editView : UIView = tabBarController.view.subviews[1] as! UIView
        editView.backgroundColor = UIColor.iStableDarkBlueTitleHeader()


}
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
```

....

Comment: You should post an explanation of your code. Additionally, things like <b> and `**` should not be in your code.